# How to properly capture return value of a command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths

I have a problem with capturing returned value of my command.

Here is my preamble with command definition:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=800x600,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Font used for writing commands.
\def\cmdFont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

% Commands.
\def\cmdOne  {\cmdFont aaa}
\def\cmdTwo  {\cmdFont bbbbb}
\def\cmdThree{\cmdFont cccc}

% Function which returns maximum width needed to write any of provided arguments.
\makeatletter

    \newlength{\textLength@getMaximumWidthHelper}
    \newlength{\textLength@getMaximumWidth}

    \newcommand{\getMaximumWidthHelper}[2]
    {%
        \settowidth{\textLength@getMaximumWidthHelper}{\pgfinterruptpicture #2\endpgfinterruptpicture}%

        \pgfmathparse{max(#1,\textLength@getMaximumWidthHelper)}%
        \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\getMaximumWidthHelper{\pgfmathresult pt}}{\pgfmathresult pt}%
    }%

    \newcommand{\getMaximumWidth}[1]
    {%
        \settowidth{\textLength@getMaximumWidth}{\pgfinterruptpicture #1\endpgfinterruptpicture}%
        \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\getMaximumWidthHelper{\the\textLength@getMaximumWidth}}{\the\textLength@getMaximumWidth}%
    }%

\makeatother
```

Working example used to test the above command:

```
\begin{document}

    \getMaximumWidth{\cmdOne}
    \getMaximumWidth{\cmdOne}{\cmdTwo}
    \getMaximumWidth{\cmdOne}{\cmdTwo}{\cmdThree}

\end{document}
```

However, when I try to capture the output of `getMaximumWidth`, it doesn't work as expected.

```
\begin{document}

    \newlength{\maximumWidth}
    \setlength{\maximumWidth}{\getMaximumWidth{\cmdOne}{\cmdTwo}{\cmdThree}}
    \the\maximumWidth

\end{document}
```

On the second line, the return value of `getMaximumWidth` is not captured but instantly printed.
Afterwards I get an error:

> ! Missing number, treated as
>   zero.

After that, the third line just prints default value `0.0pt`.

What is the proper way to capture the output of `getMaximumWidth`?

P.S. This is my first time writing Latex document, feel free to point out anything i could've done better.

Comment: while `\@ifnextchar\bgroup` works you should almost never do it as it results in commands that fail to obey latex syntax conventions. All latex commands have a fixed number of arguments using `{}` delimiters and a variable number of optional arguments which use `[]` delimiters. You have defined a command with optional `{}` arguments which is wrong.

Comment: macros do not have return values, your `\getMaximumWidth` expands to a series of assignments so is not a length that can be used in `\setlength`, you need to define it to leave a length in some command, say `\tempresult` then use `\getMaximumWidth{\cmdOne}{\cmdTwo}{\cmdThree}\setlength{\maximumWidth}{\tempresult}` or using a latex-conforming syntax, `\getMaximumWidth{\cmdOne,\cmdTwo,\cmdThree}\setlength{\maximumWidth}{\tempresult}`

Comment: That is exactly why `\pgfmathparse` leaves its answer in `\pgfmathresult`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am not able to test everything at the moment, but your solution seems a lot easier and can be used as I intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd generalize `\settowidth` and, by the way, get also height and depth for free.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\settomaximumwidth}{mm}
 {% #1 = length, #2 = comma separated list of objects
  \iskustvo_settomaxdim:Nnn \settowidth { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\settomaximumheight}{mm}
 {% #1 = length, #2 = comma separated list of objects
  \iskustvo_settomaxdim:Nnn \settoheight { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\settomaximumdepth}{mm}
 {% #1 = length, #2 = comma separated list of objects
  \iskustvo_settomaxdim:Nnn \settodepth { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\dim_new:N \l__iskustvo_tempa_dim
\dim_new:N \l__iskustvo_tempb_dim
\tl_new:N \l__iskustvo_temp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \iskustvo_settomaxdim:Nnn
 {
  \dim_zero:N \l__iskustvo_tempa_dim
  \clist_map_variable:nNn { #3 } \l__iskustvo_temp_tl
   { \__iskustvo_measure:N #1 }
  \dim_set_eq:NN #2 \l__iskustvo_tempa_dim
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iskustvo_measure:N
 {
  #1{\l__iskustvo_tempb_dim}{\l__iskustvo_temp_tl}
  \dim_set:Nn \l__iskustvo_tempa_dim
   {
    \dim_max:nn { \l__iskustvo_tempa_dim } { \l__iskustvo_tempb_dim }
   }
 } 
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Font used for writing commands.
\def\cmdFont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

% Commands.
\def\cmdOne  {\cmdFont aaa}
\def\cmdTwo  {\cmdFont bbbbb}
\def\cmdThree{\cmdFont cccc}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\test}

\settomaximumwidth{\test}{\cmdOne,\cmdTwo,\cmdThree}
\the\test

\settomaximumheight{\test}{\cmdOne,\cmdTwo,\cmdThree}
\the\test

\settomaximumdepth{\test}{\cmdOne,\cmdTwo,\cmdThree}
\the\test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I won't lie, I have absolutely no idea what you did, but the usage at the end is pretty neat.

Comment: I've read a bit and now that I understand what you did with this Elvish syntax, it's even more impressive! Luckily I think I'll just need the width, so I'll dumb it down a little.

Answer (score 6):

I would write this something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\cmdFont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}% this is the default anyway

% Commands.
\newcommand\cmdOne  {\cmdFont aaa}
\newcommand\cmdTwo  {\cmdFont bbbbb}
\newcommand\cmdThree{\cmdFont cccc}


\newlength{\maximumWidth}

\newcommand{\getMaximumWidth}[1]{%
\settowidth\maximumWidth{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\getMaximumWidth{\cmdOne\\ \cmdTwo\\ \cmdThree}

\the\maximumWidth

\end{document}
```